# Using $http with google suggestions - Convert from angularjs version 1.3.15 to version 1.6.4

Tags: angularjs, http, search

First of all, I don't know much about angularjs.  I did manage to patch together a single file web page with angularjs.  I am having trouble converting the $http call from version 1.3.15 to version 1.6.4 as shown in the following:

```
var url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&client=firefox&hl=en&q=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchText);
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http({
  url: url,
  method: 'JSONP',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.suggestions = data[1];
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.suggestions = ['error connecting'];
  });
```

Not real sure how it should look.

Here is the whole file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<style>
  #appDiv
  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 80%;
    transform: translate(-80%, 0%);
    width:50%;
  }

  #entry
  {
    width: 100%
  }

  #searchInput 
  { 
    display: table-cell;
    color: #808080;
    width:100%;
    font-size:150%;
  }

  .goButton
  {
    font-size:150%;
  }

  .list 
  { 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: default;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #DFDFDF;
  }
  .list:empty
  {
    border-style: none;
  }

  .listItem
  {
    color: #404040;
    font-size:120%;
  }
  .listItem:hover 
  { 
    background: #DFDFDF; 

  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="appDiv" ng-app="googleSearch" ng-controller="googleCtrl">
  <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" autocomplete="off">
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td id="entry">
          <input type="text" name="q" id="searchInput" autofocus="autofocus"  maxlength="255" ng-model="searchText" ng-keyup="search()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="goButton" type="submit" value="      Go!      "/>
          <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" ng-mouseleave="restore()">
          <ul class="list"><li class="listItem" ng-repeat="x in suggestions" ng-click="select(x)" ng-mouseover="preview(x)">{{x}}</li></ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("googleSearch", []);

app.controller("googleCtrl", function($scope, $http) 
{

$scope.select = function(text)
{
  $scope.searchText = text;
  $scope.memory = text;
  $scope.suggestions = [];
  document.getElementById("searchInput").focus();
}

$scope.preview = function(text)
{
  $scope.searchText = text;
}

$scope.restore = function()
{
  $scope.searchText = $scope.memory;
}

$scope.search = function()
{
  $scope.memory = $scope.searchText;
  googleSearch();
}

googleSearch = function() 
{
  if ($scope.searchText == null || $scope.searchText.length < 1)
  {
    $scope.suggestions = [];
    return
  }
  var url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&client=firefox&hl=en&q=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchText);
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
$http({
  url: url,
  method: 'JSONP',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.suggestions = data[1];
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.suggestions = ['error connecting'];
  });
}
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am having trouble with the googleSearch function when I use:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
```

in the head element.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`success`and `error` are deprecated in `$http` api in favor of using promise callback

Also *Access Control* headers are for CORS and are only set on server as response headers not in request headers.

JSONP requests aaccept no headers since they are actually script requests no XMLHttpRequests.

you must now also declare JSONP url's as `$sce` trusted urls. Be sure to include angular-santize.js in page and inject `$sce`

Use `then()` and `catch()`

Try:

```
var url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&hl=en&q=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchText);
var truestedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
$http.jsonp(truestedUrl , {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'}).then(function(response) {
  $scope.suggestions = response.data[1];
}).catch(function(error) {
  $scope.suggestions = ['error connecting'];
});
```

Reference [$http.jsonp() docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp)

Comment: Thanks this worked.  I had to put <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-sanitize.js"></script> in the head and change the controller to: app.controller("googleCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce)

Comment: Right...that's why I mentioned including it and injecting $sce

Answer (score 0):

Final Google search file using angularjs 1.6.4

I just thought I would post my final result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<style>
  #appDiv
  {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 65%;
    transform: translate(-65%, 0%);
    width:50%;
  }

  #entry
  {
    width: 100%
  }

  #searchInput 
  { 
    display: table-cell;
    color: #000000;
    width:100%;
    font-size:150%;
  }

  .goButton
  {
    font-size:150%;
  }

  input[type=submit] 
  {
    padding:7px 0px 7px 0px;; 
    background: #00ff00;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px; 
  }

  .list 
  { 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: default;
  }

  .listItem
  {
    color: #000000;
    font-size:150%;
  }
  .listItem:hover 
  { 
    background: #DFDFDF; 
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="appDiv" ng-app="googleSearch" ng-controller="googleCtrl">
  <form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" autocomplete="off">
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td id="entry">
          <input type="text" name="q" id="searchInput" autofocus="autofocus"  maxlength="255" ng-model="searchText" ng-keyup="search()" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input class="goButton" type="submit" value="      Go!      "/>
          <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" ng-mouseleave="restore()">
          <ul class="list"><li class="listItem" ng-repeat="x in suggestions" ng-click="select(x)" ng-mouseover="preview(x)">{{x}}</li></ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("googleSearch", []);

app.controller("googleCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $sce) 
{
  $scope.select = function(text)
  {
    $scope.searchText = text;
    $scope.memory = text;
    $scope.suggestions = [];
    document.getElementById("searchInput").focus();
    googleSearch();
  }

  $scope.preview = function(text)
  {
    $scope.searchText = text;
  }

  $scope.restore = function()
  {
    $scope.searchText = $scope.memory;
  }

  $scope.search = function()
  {
    $scope.memory = $scope.searchText;
    googleSearch();
  }

  googleSearch = function() 
  {
    if ($scope.searchText == null || $scope.searchText.length < 1)
    {
      $scope.suggestions = [];
      return
    }

    var url = 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&hl=en&q=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchText);
    var truestedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);

    $http.jsonp(truestedUrl , {jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback'}).then(function(response) {
      $scope.suggestions = response.data[1];
    }).catch(function(error) {
      $scope.suggestions = [];
    });

} 
}]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```